# How do I write a program that reads array in from text file and finds max and min?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, io, format

I have been tasked with writing a code that reads numbers in from a txt file array and finding the max, min, sum etc. The (200) numbers are in the format:
3.23
19.398
98.73
2.1
...
Sorry if the code is a bit of a mess, I've been trying to piece together a lot of different tutorials to no avail. I basically need to know how to get the code to read the values sequentially, and pull out the max/min values and keep going through the array. (and find sum along the way) How do I format this correctly?

```
# include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    //char data[200];
int newnum;
int max = 0, min = 99999999999;
int i = 0;
int y[200];
//min=max=newnum;

FILE *fpdata = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if((fpdata = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == 0)
    {
        printf("File not found.  Abort!");
        exit(-1);
    }


    while(fscanf(fpdata,"%f", &y[i++]) != EOF);{
    //for(i=0; i < 200; i++)

        i--;
        printf("i=%d \n", i);
        //printf("\n%d%d\n", &y[i++], y);
        if(newnum > max)
        max = newnum;

        if(newnum < min)
        min = newnum;
    }


    printf("The largest number is %d\n", max);
    printf("The smallest number is %d\n", min);
    fclose(fpdata);


    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried utilizing all possible resources (youtube, other stackoverflow questions) for hours but none explicitly lay out how to format the call in array from the file, read, and pluck values from it.

Comment: `FILE *fpdata = fopen("input1.txt", "r");` -> `FILE *fpdata;`

Comment: `EOF);{` --> `EOF){` (i.e. remove the `;`)

Comment: You never assign anything to `newnum`. Probably just replace `&y[i++]` by `&newnum`.

Comment: You scan  `int` but the format look as if the file contain floats

Comment: Why not check each value for max/min as it is read in instead of trying to read them all with that nasty while() loop and then iterating the array after?   Try very hard to not write code like that - it's very difficult to debug one-liner complex statements/expressions ,(not to speak of being difficult to understand).

Comment: The input is float numbers but you read it as integers. How does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- You scan for `float` but store data as `int`
- You `open` the file twice
- You have an unintended `;` at the end of the `while`
- The loop condition (i.e. `!= EOF`) may cause an infinite loop in the file contains something that can't be parsed as a float. Using `== 1` is safer.
- Your initialization of max and min can be improved

After fixing that the program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) 
{
  float newnum;
  float max = -FLT_MAX;
  float min = FLT_MAX;

  FILE *fpdata;
  if((fpdata = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == 0)
  {
    printf("File not found.  Abort!");
    exit(-1);
  }

  while(fscanf(fpdata,"%f", &newnum) == 1)
  {
    printf("%f\n", newnum);
    if(newnum > max) max = newnum;
    if(newnum < min) min = newnum;
  }

  printf("The largest number is %f\n", max);
  printf("The smallest number is %f\n", min);
  fclose(fpdata);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues:

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                   // include also stdlib.h

int main()
{
  float newnum;
  float max = 0, min = 99999999999;   // use float type for float numbers
  int i = 0;    
  FILE *fpdata;     // callign fopen only once

  if ((fpdata = fopen("data.txt", "r")) == 0)
  {
    printf("File not found.  Abort!");
    exit(-1);
  }

  while (fscanf(fpdata, "%f", &newnum) != EOF) {    // removed extra ;
    printf("i = %d, newnum = %f\n", i++, newnum);   // reading into newnum 
                                                    // correct format specifiers

    if (newnum > max)
      max = newnum;

    if (newnum < min)
      min = newnum;
  }

  printf("The largest number is %f\n", max);  // correct format specifiers
  printf("The smallest number is %f\n", min);
  fclose(fpdata);

  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for improvments though.

Here is the version that first reads all the data into the `data` array (`data` is a nicer name than `y`) and then does the calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  float max = 0, min = 99999999999;
  float data[200];

  FILE *fpdata;

  if ((fpdata = fopen("input1.txt", "r")) == 0)
  {
    printf("File not found.  Abort!");
    exit(-1);
  }

  int nbofnumbers = 0;
  while (fscanf(fpdata, "%f", &data[nbofnumbers]) != EOF)
  {
    nbofnumbers++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nbofnumbers; i++)
  {
    printf("data[%d] = %f\n", i, data[i]);
    if (data[i] > max)
      max = data[i];

    if (data[i] < min)
      min = data[i];
  }

  printf("The largest number is %f\n", max);
  printf("The smallest number is %f\n", min);
  fclose(fpdata);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A few suggestions: `max = -FLT_MAX, min = FLT_MAX` and `while (fscanf(fpdata, "%f", &newnum)  == 1)`

Comment: @4386427 correct, but as I wrote: _There is still room for improvments_

Comment: yes, I noticed that so I just added a few suggestions that OP can consider to include. It is **not** meant as a critique of your answer but using ` != EOF` is pretty "dangerous" as the program will loop forever if the input file contains something that can't be passed as a float.